# How can I make fullscreen cross hairs appear centered on the pointer?

Tags: gui, utilities, measure

How can I make fullscreen crosshairs, centered on the mouse, appear on my screen?  I read a lot of science papers with graphs that I want to quickly be able to see what feature is horizontal/vertical with another feature.

I'm looking for something like the below screenshot of LibreCAD, but for the entire screen.

[image]

I searched the repositories with

```
$ apt-cache search cross | grep hair
```

amongst other attempts, and wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find what you are looking for in the applications dealing with *assistive technology*, e.g., screen magnification.

Here are a few links which describe applications:

- [Magnification in GNOME Shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Magnification)
- [Zoom Options Dialog (Universal Access)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Magnification/ZoomOptionsDialog)
- [Gnome Magnifier Review](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accessibility/Reviews/gnome-mag)
- [Cursor as full screen crosshairs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48515/cursor-as-full-screen-crosshairs)